# What is $R$-symmetry with supersymmetric theory?

Tags: symmetry, definition, supersymmetry

What is $R$-charge and [$R$-symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-symmetry)?

In usual context, $\mathcal{N}=2$ supersymmetry has $U(1)$ $R$-symmetry.
I don't understand what this means. Could you explain to me with more examples? $R$-symmetry with relevant gauge groups would be helpful.

For example in $d=7$, $\mathcal{N}=2$ supergravity we have R symmetry $R=sp(2)$. I wonder where this comes from.

Comment: I have only skimmed through supersymmetry, but I have usually encountered $U(2)=SU(2) \times U(1)$ $R$-symmetry where $sp(2) \sim su(2)$. I.e. you generalize straightforwardly the $\mathcal{N}=1$ case. Apart from things written in Luboš's answer, you can see why it makes the equations "look nice" in chapter 5 [here](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~rargurio/susycourse.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An R-symmetry is any global symmetry that transforms the supercharge or supercharges – often in a theory with extended supersymmetry,  one in which the supersymmetry generators $Q_i^\alpha$ carry an extra internal index $i$ – into each other. It is typically $U(1)$ for non-extended $N=1$ supersymmetry and becomes non-Abelian, like $SU(2)$ or $SU(4)$, in extended SUSY.

Comment: I noticed that you added a link - and you are aware - of the Wikipedia entry on that. What's wrong with that? I am unhappy to hear it was not useful because I started that Wikipedia page, too. ;-)

Comment: Well, i did not added a link to the question, it was done by Qmechanic i guess. What i try to do is understand R symmetry in more conceptually. For example in $d=7$, $N=2$ supergravty we have R symmetry $R=sp(2)$. I wonder how this comes from

Comment: The theory simply has this symmetry. Note that $Sp(2)$ is often just a fancy name for $USp(2)$ which is isomorphic to $SU(2)$. You write down the lagrangian or equations of motion and see that the supercharges may be transformed in the most obvious way by an $SU(2)$ into each other. Each theory has different symmetries in general. So if you ask about an example and you don't really know how to derive it yourself, you won't know how to derive the symmetry group in other theories, anyway. Do you understand what $SU(2)$ means? I don't know what may be hard about the existence of an $SU(2)$.

Comment: @LubošMotl: Why can't I have a group which is larger than SU(N)? say $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ for example?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac Take the N-extended supersymmetry algebra and assume a $GL(N,\mathbb{C})$ transformation on the supercharges and then require that the $\{Q^a,Q^b\}=\delta^{ab} P$ anticommutator be unchanged. This will quickly impose a condition on the arbitrary linear transformation that you propose. Notation: I have hidden the Lorentz indices, assumed that $Q$ is a Dirac spinor (rather than the usual Weyl notation common in $d=4$) and $a,b=1,\ldots,N$.

Comment: @Lubos Motl, Thanks a lot, your second explanation about SP(2) helps me a lot. ^.^ I have been make some table about R-symmetry group based on some materials, doing that i just came up with question as how can i justify them. Your reply helps me a lot

Answer (score 8):

To be precise (I just saw this post), without really complicating the discussion:

the R-symmetry is the largest subgroup of the automorphisms group of the supersymmetry algebra which commutes with the Lorentz group. In simple words, there exists a group which commutes with the Lorentz group AND leaves the susy algebra (the anticommutators) invariant. The largest such group is referred to as R-symmetry. (see http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212245 for instance)

The important, but often neglected point, is that the R-symmetry needs NOT be a symmetry of the theory at all. Sometimes it is, sometimes it is NOT.